# 2's complement data representation

Tags: binary, computer-science, decimal, radix, twos-complement

This is a question which I saw in a past paper. I think I understand 10s complement, but don't understand the following question about two's compliment. Also, what does two's compliment have to do with binary?

> What number in base 10 is represented by 1110 in 2s complements with k=4? Would the answer change if k=5?

Please Explain the answer, thanks for any help!

Comment: Is k the maximum number of bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two's complement is a method to represent negaitve numbers in binary. I don't understand how it works, but it does, there is mathematical foundation behind it.
take for example the number 6. In binary it's 0110. Then to represent -6  you need to apply two's complement algorithm on it.

The algorithm is to copy all the digits from right to left. The first time you encounter 1 you leave it as it is, but from that point on you invert all the digits as you advance left. In this example let's go right to left: First we have 0. Then we have 1. We copy it, so meanwhile we have 10. Since we encountered 1 we now need to invert all the bits. So the next one is 1, we copy it as 0, so we now have 010. The leftmost bit is 0 so we invert it to 1 and so we end up with 1010. This is -6 in 4 digit. Negative numbers in two's complement always have 1 for MSB (the leftmost bit - Most Significant Bit).

Before I continue, there is a short way for the conversion. you simply invert all the bits then add 1, and get the same result. If we invert 0110 we get 1001. Adding 1 gives, again 1010. Don't know how it works but it does.

How much is 8 - 6? It's like 8 + (-6). In two's complement it's 1000 + 1010 = 10010

Since we work with 4 digits, we trim the MSB and get 0010 which is 2, which is 8 - 6. It works.

If you take -6 (1010) and apply the two's complement on it again, you get (using the second method) invert(1010) + 1 = 0101 + 1 = 0110 = 6. So applying two's complement algorithm to negative numbers reveals their absolute value.

And now we can move on to the second part of your question: 1110. In the positive numbers world this is 14. But in the workd of both positive and negative numbers, we see that since the MSB (most signigicant bit) in this number is 1, the number is negative. Like in the -6 example, applying to it two's complement will give it's absolute value. Hence: Invert(1110) + 1 = 0001 + 1 = 0010 = 2. So 1110 is -2.

I beleive that k in the question is number of digits. If k is 5 then how do we represent -2?

To answer that we start with 2 represented in 5 digits, and then apply the two's complement conversion.

2 is 00010. Two's complent on it is invert(00010) + 1 = 11101 + 1 = 11110.

You can conclude that if we had 8 bits then -2 would be 11111110.

This phenomenon is called sign extension. It says that if a negative number can be represented in k bits, then: a) the MSB will be 1, and b) if you want to use more than k bits, then all the bits from the original MSB and left will all be 1.

And again, there is mathematics behind it to prove it, which I'm not familiar with.

By the way, you can look in my website. It happened that your question hits exactly the problem I solve in a product called ChordBits, where you can turn bits on and off, and among other options, you can apply two's complement on them and view what it looks like (the shareware version is fully functional). [www.codechords.com](http://www.codechords.com)

Cheers

Comment: It's interesting to note that the applying the infinite exponential series summation formula to compute sum[i=0..inf](2^n) yields -1.  So if one regards the most significant bit as being sign extended out an infinite number of bits, the computer's two's complement form is consistent with the mathematical meaning of binary numbers.